# How to apply numerical referencing with APA in MS Word?

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-office, citations

I am using MS Word referencing functionality and I want to reference the sources by numbers while using APA style?

For example:

```
... see [1].

References:

[1] Rong, X. (2014). word2vec parameter learning explained. arXiv preprint arXiv:1411.2738.
```

How to do that?

Note: ISO-690 style has numerical referencing like `(1)`, but I want to use `[1]` in the text and APA style in the references table.

Answer (score 1):

APA does not support numerical referencing; what you're asking for is a violation of the APA referencing format.

In any event, this is an end-user question, not a programming one. As such, it is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I think this can be done by modifying this file: %AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\LiveContent\16\Managed\Word Document Bibliography Styles\TM02851216[[fn=apasixtheditionofficeonline]].xsl

For that reason, I asked here.

Comment: Well, if you really want to go down that path, see: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=bibword & https://sourceforge.net/p/bibutils/home/Bibutils/. Do be aware, though, that whatever customisations you make will affect only your system; anyone you send the document to will still see it with standard APA referencing.